# How to use an external static library in a Qt project in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake, lib, .a

I am trying to import an external static library in my project. I have added `.h` files in my Qt Project and added the static library via the import external library option.

`test.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST_LIB_H 
#define TEST_LIB_H 

int Start_test(); 

#endif // TEST_LIB_H
```

`test.c`:

```
#include "../inc/test.h" 

int Start_test() 
{ 
    int a =4;
    int b =1;
    int somme =a+b;

    return somme; 
}
```

`pro` file:

```
CONFIG += c++11 

LIBS += -lws2_32 win32: 
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../testLib/lib/ -ltest 

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../testLib 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../testLib 

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../testLib/lib/test.lib 
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../testLib/lib/libtest.a
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
Undefined reference to 'Start_test'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Note:** I am using **MingW** for compiling the library and the Qt project.

Tried to place it in the same folder as the Qt project, but same result.

Comment: Could you mention how exactly you added this library, step by step, and post your `.pro` file (I'm guessing you're using qmake since you can use Add library option), and how are you including this library in your code? see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) for more information if you haven't. And if you could, mention what is this library you're using and what functions are undefined, post the full error output.

Comment: If you're trying to use this library in a big project, try testing it in a new empty project, so you can isolate the problem.

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene I clicked the right button chose the "Add Library option" and selected my library "libtest.a" selected "Windows" and the "static" options. he library is simply a test library that I've created containing a basic function summing two constants.

######This is my test.h#########
#ifndef TEST_LIB_H
#define TEST_LIB_H
    int Start_test();
#endif // TEST_LIB_H

#########This is my test.c########
#include "../inc/test.h"
int Start_test()
{
    
    int a =4;
    int b =1;
    int somme =a+b;
    return somme;
}

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene
###This my .pro file
CONFIG += c++11
LIBS += -lws2_32
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../testLib/lib/ -ltest
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../testLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../testLib
win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../testLib/lib/test.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../testLib/lib/libtest.a
 I Tried the library in an empty project and the same linking error appeared

Comment: You're including a `test.h` in your `test.c`, whereas your `pro` file is linking a `libtest.a`, try including that instead, and see if it works.

Comment: and it seems that you'll also need to copy the contents of `test.h` to `libtest.a`, since it is the external static library that you should be using, you can notice that you cannot add a `.h` library as an external library.